# Is there a version of Autofac for WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, autofac

I have a windows phone 7 application that I would like to port to WinRT. My app currently uses Autofac and I am wondering if there is a version for WinRT around.  I have been unable to find any information about this.

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know when will be a dedicated version of Autofac for WinRT but from the [Autofac 2.6.1 release notes](http://nblumhardt.com/2012/03/autofac-update-2-6-1-published/):

```
Autofac can now be used with .NET Portable Class Libraries.
```

And the [.Net Portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be used from WinRT.

Currently there is no nuget package for it but it is [directly downloadable](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/detail?name=Autofac-2.6.1.841-Portable.zip) from the Autofac website.

Note this version is not final just a "preview", you can find more info in the google groups: [Support for Windows Runtime](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/autofac/yokgnLr_tho).